# FOR loop in batch script not working properly

Tags: batch-file

I have written a script where forloop set the variable "project" and use the variable in call `:Project_check`. Where in `:Project_check` function the `if` condition check is not working even the Condition is matched , it runs fine when I check separately. And in log I can see SET Project value is correct but `if` loop not working when it called from `for` loop

```
goto :FOR_loop

:FOR_loop

FOR %%G IN (project1 project2 project3) DO (
    SET PROJECT=%%G
    call :PROJECT_CHECK
    exit /b
)


:PROJECT_CHECK
if "%PROJECT%"=="project1" SET location=Home1&call :Copy
if "%PROJECT%"=="project2" SET location=Home2&call :Copy
if "%PROJECT%"=="project3" SET location=Home3&call :Copy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am honestly not sure what the purpose is of your method, but I am sure there is a much better method, if only I could see the `:Copy` Label. Anyway you are calling `exit /b` inside the loop and couple other issues with your code. I added a dummy `:Copy` label to my code to simulate.. Also note that I wrap my `set` variables in double quotes to eliminate possible whitespace.

```
@echo off
goto :FOR_loop

:FOR_loop
for %%G IN (project1 project2 project3) DO (
    set "project=%%G"
    if defined project call :PROJECT_CHECK
)
exit /b

:PROJECT_CHECK

if "%project%"=="project1" SET "location=Home1" & call :Copy
if "%project%"=="project2" SET "location=Home2" & call :Copy
if "%project%"=="project3" SET "location=Home3" & call :Copy
exit /b
:Copy
echo %project% %location%
```

Comment: its due to exit /b, Thanks @Gerhard Barnard for your quick response :)